# What is the purpose of a xHCI controller while esxi6 doesn't support USB3?

Tags: vmware-esxi, usb, passthrough

When I add a virtual xHCI controller to my Linux VM on an esxi6 host, plug some USB3 device
to a blue USB 3.0 SuperSpeed port on the server and connect this device to the VM,
I get only USB2 speed.
`lsusb` reports the device being on a USB2 controller
not only in the VM but also in the esxi6 host (USB3 controller visible, but unused). Host:

```
# lsusb | sort
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0480:d010 Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc. External Disk 3TB
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

VM:

```
# lsusb | sort
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0480:d010 Toshiba America Inc External Disk 3TB
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

`vmkload_mod xhci` reports: `module is already loaded` (not by me, but automatically on esxi6 boot).
Googling reveals that [esxi6 does not support USB 3.0](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/No-USB-3-0-on-ESXi-6/m-p/1812307).
From the [official VMware docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-EC20F765-4C1A-4D04-881A-945702328FEB.html): *For virtual machines with Linux guests, [...] 3.0 superspeed devices are not supported for passthrough from an ESXi host to a virtual machine.*

So what is the purpose of having a virtual xHCI controller which cannot be used ?

Or to ask the question the other way:
How can I use the xHCI controller in my VM ?

The physical USB3 controller on the mainboard has vendor:product 8086:8c31 which is reported as *USB controller Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller* by `lspci -v` on the VMware esxi6 host.
The generic Linux `pci.ids` file lists this vendor:product as *8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI*.

Comment: Is the USB Controller in your VM set to `USB 3.0`?

Comment: What do you mean with _set_ ? When installing a virtual xHCI controller in VMware, one gets a USB 2.0 root hub and a USB 3.0 root hub in the VM. This is the same as with other physical USB 3.0 controllers on bare metal. I don't know of any settings in the VM. I'm editing the question to contain `lsusb` VM output.

Comment: On my ESXi 6.5 I have a single USB controller where I can select between 2.0 and 3.0, hence my asking.

Comment: At which place are you able to _select_ ? On the VMware host or in the VM guest ? What type of software is offering choices to you ?

Answer (score 2):

ESXi supports USB 3.0 since version 5.5 Update 3. However, for some reason you need to manually load/activate the xhci module in ESXi to enable the support:

```
esxcli system module load -m xhci
esxcli system module set -e true -m xhci
```

See e.g. this blog post for details: https://www.v-front.de/2014/11/vmware-silently-adds-native-usb-30.html

Comment: I have read that blog post including all the comments but that did not help:  
`vmkload_mod xhci` reports: `module is already loaded`.  This seems to be expected because I'm using esxi6 _where xhci should work out of the box_ according to one of those comments. Updated the question.